# Can I change word order in this sentence with "immer"?

Tags: sentence-structure

I just read a sentence in my textbook:

> Mein schönstes deutsches Wort lautet "Sternschnuppe", weil man nach einer Sternschnuppe immer einen Wunsch frei hat.

I think that "immer" is about time, so according to the time-manner-place order, shouldn't it be

> ... weil man immer nach einer Sternschnuppe einen Wunsch frei hat

?

Answer (score 5):

Grammar-wise both sentences are fine. However, the first one with

> ... weil man nach einer Sternschnuppe immer einen Wunsch frei hat

is the more natural way of speaking.

I suppose the reason is as follows:

The "immer" works like a sign-post like: "Attention! Now something crucial is going to be said!", and thus it lets the audience focus on the element **directly following**.

In the first (more natural) sentence, this is "einen Wunsch frei haben". Which is indeed the specific thing - the core of the proposition.

Whereas in

> ... weil man immer nach einer Sternschnuppe einen Wunsch frei hat.

the element following directly on "immer" is "Sternschnuppe", so focus is laid on "Sternschnuppe". This may be appropriate in certain situations, but not in your case, as you had mentioned that Sternschnuppe already, so it is anyway present in the mind of your audience, and now everybody is just waiting what exactly you are going to tell about Sternschnuppen.

A sentence with "immer nach einer Sternschnuppe" would need something to be said where focus on Sternschnuppe makes sense. For example:

> Ich mag Sternschnuppen lieber als Meteoriten, weil man **immer bei einer Sternschnuppe** einen Wunsch frei hat, aber bei einem Meteoriten nicht.

---

Disclaimer: in my experience wishing things on the sight of a Sternschnuppe has no effect. None of the wishes I spent on them became true so far.

(Okay, perhaps it is just because each Sternschnuppe is only for one wish, and every time somebody else is quicker. Perhaps there are too many people on earth, and too little Sternschnuppen around.)

Answer (score 3):

No, **immer** is a manner, and **nach** is a time relation.

> **Wann** steht er auf? — Er steht **nach ihr** auf.
>
> Aber **nur** wochentags, oder? — Nein, er steht **immer** nach ihr auf.

But both sentences are okay, as Christian explained.

Comment: "Nach ihr steht immer er auf"; "Immer steht er nach ihr auf", ...

Comment: Yes, these are interchangeable, as Christian explained.

Comment: The art of the short answer...

Comment: @tofro This isn't interchangeable if you have three persions. "Nach ihr immer er" means that he rises immediately. "Immer steht er nach ihr auf" allows to have a third  person rising between them.

Comment: @harper We don't have three persons in that sentence. And all other possible word orders really don't nail third persons to their seats as well, allowing them to rise whenever they want.

Comment: @tofro The sentence isn't so interesting w/o a story and the story can have more pepole. Assuming that there are more than "er" and "sie" the first phrase "nach ihr immer er" excludes any other person to rise after her. The word "imme" emphases that's he who rises. You don't find this in the second phrase "Immer steht er nach ihr auf" that doesn’t exclude other people, does it?

Comment: @harper Could all well be. But we don't know, as we don't have more context. As it stands, we have a temporal relationship between two people rising from their chairs, nothing more.

Comment: @tofro Since you ignore my statement that "immer er" excludes a third person between them, we can agree that we disagree. If you like you can read my first comment what clearly says, when my arguments apply.

Comment: I agree with @harper, "Nach ihr steht immer er auf" doesn't make sense if there are no alternatives to "him". The catch is that the nesting changes: In the first case "immer" only modifies "er" ("immer *er* - und nicht jemand anders"), in the second it modifies the whole verb phrase ("immer *steht er auf* - und tut nichts anderes").

Comment: The same can be applied to the original example, btw. [Nach einer Sternschnuppe] hat man immer *einen Wunsch frei*  vs. immer *nach einer Sternschnuppe* [hat man einen Wunsch frei]. Luckily, this time the swap does not change the meaning of the sentence, so these two are actually interchangeable.